# select statement without where clause in Dapper targeting .net3.5 framework

Tags: c#, dapper

I am using Dapper micro-ORM in my project where i want to select all the records from table. Below is my code.

```
 var result = connection.Query<Department>("Select * From Department");
```

and i am getting the following error

```
No Overload for method 'Query' takes 1 argument
```

My project's target framework is .net 3.5. If i just change the project's target framework to .net 4.0, and re-install dapper (using nuget) everything is working good.

i don't want to use where clause (i.e. no additional parameter for query method). Is there a way to run this query using dapper targeting .net 3.5 framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current code, you *must* pass a `param` argument in the NET35 build. This can be `null`. Try:

```
var result = connection.Query<Department>("select * from Department", null);
```

Comment: and if that doesn't work, let me know and I'll deploy the code to NuGet